# "TemplateDoesNotExist at /my_app_name" but Template-loader postmortem says "(File exists)"

Tags: python, django, templates, loader

I am getting the following error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /app1/1/about/
>
> index/index.html

but Template-loader postmortem says:

> /var/www/web/sites/mysite.com/app1/templates/index/index.html (File exists)

I have tried all stackoverflow's answers on similar questions, but they didn't work for me. On my local server(running on OSX, virtualenv) everything is alright, but on production server I'm getting this error. On production server I'm using Django 1.7.5 on Ubuntu 14 with virtualenv.
Each app has it`s own template, the structure is like this:

```
app1
--templates
----index
------index.html
------head.html views.py app2
--templates
----index
------index.html
------head.html views.py
```

In settings.py I have the following parameters for templates:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # django
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     # widgets
     'widget_tweaks',
     'compressor',
     'tinymce',
     'django_activeurl',
     'debug_toolbar',
     # modules
     'app1',
     'app2',
 )
```

and including them in views like this:

```
template_event = loader.get_template('index/materials.html', dirs=["app1/templates/"])
```

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /app1/1/about/ index/index.html. There is a space before first 'index'

Comment: You don't have a directory called `index/` unless you failed to include it in your example.

Comment: But.. on local server everything works fine, I'm confused.

Comment: I thought that the problem is in paths, but why it says that file exists...

Comment: Specifying `dirs` in `load_templates` is unusual. If your settings are correct it shouldn't be required. Using a relative directory `'app1/templates/'` might cause problems.

Comment: without this parameter loader gets templates from project's root folder, the only solution I see is to name templates like 'app1_index' and etc..

Comment: Also, make sure that any capital letters match. Ubuntu is case sensitive but your dev environment on a mac is case insensitive.

Comment: the message that file exists, I think, means that the template is found, but can't be loaded, doesn't it?

Comment: Usually, the recommendation is to put an `app1` subdirectory i.e. `app1/templates/app1/`, and load `app1/index/materials.html`. Then `dirs` is unnecessary, in `load_templates`, and the template should be loaded from the correct directory.

Comment: I have missed thad when posted the question. I have the same structure as you say...

Comment: Yes, the 'File exists' suggests that the template can be found but not loaded. Check its ownership and permissions, and make sure that it does not `include` or extend` another template that does not exist.

Comment: Ok, will try to change permissions... Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Do you have a `templates` directory that is not inside any application directory?

Comment: yes, I have, in project`s root, but on local server everything works.

Comment: Changing folder's permissions doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the template loader by passing in the `dirs` argument, which overrides whatever is in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

First, you don't need to set `TEMPLATE_DIRS` if all your templates are included inside app directories. The `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable exists if you want to load templates from *other file system locations*. If all your templates are in `app/templates/`, then you don't need to set `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

Since you are trying to load a template that is part of an application, simply pass the relative path to the template:

```
template_event = loader.get_template('index/materials.html')
```

Now, here is what django is gong to do (highly simplified):

1. First, it will look at TEMPLATE_LOADERS and then call each of the loader for its templates. The first loader is the file system loader, which will use the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting to find any templates. If a template here matches the path, then it will stop.
2. The next loader is the `app_directories` loader, this loader will look for a directory named `templates` in any app that is added to `INSTALLED_APPS` and then return the first template that matches.

The postmartem is telling you that the loaders have found your template, but the way you are asking them to load templates - they cannot find the template.

Comment: It has partically worked, but now I get error in template, including file from another app...    "{% include "misc/menu.html" %}", the same templatedoesntexists error

Comment: That's something else entirely.

Comment: Strange logic of django, I think. In my opinion, it should act like this: try to find template from TEMPLATE_DIRS, and if there is no template, load it from INSTALLED_APPS directories, but thank you for your answer, anyway. Will mark it as answer.

Comment: That's exactly how it works - but you passed in `dirs` argument, which threw the entire system off.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized my mistake, after deep reading of django documentation, figured out that [Alsadair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) was right with his answer in comments.

> Usually, the recommendation is to put an app1 subdirectory i.e.
>   app1/templates/app1/, and load app1/index/materials.html. Then dirs is
>   unnecessary, in load_templates, and the template should be loaded from
>   the correct directory.